# Installing nyt streamtools: go-bindata: Command not found

Tags: go, centos6

I am trying to install nyt streamtools, the open-source project for ETL, but I can't seem to get my go environment right.  I'm running Centos 6.5.  Compiling from source should be easy, but I keep getting this error when I run the `make` command:

```
localhost streamtools]$ make

go get github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/...

go-bindata -pkg=server -o st/server/static_bindata.go gui/... examples/...

make: go-bindata: Command not found

make: *** [build/st] Error 127
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried installing go-bindata?

Comment: I gave installed go-bindata in my local directory, but I still get the same error.  Is there something I need to do to make bindata available?

Comment: Is the folder in which the go-bindata executable resides on your PATH?

Comment: I have a $GOPATH/bin several directories above my working directory. Home is GOPATH/$HOME/go

Comment: ARGHHH.  Thanks for  your help everyone!  I forgot to source my .bashrc after setting my GOPATH and PATH.  For others with this issue, I added these two lines to my ~/.bashrc:

export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

Answer (score 3):

Added lines to ~/.bashrc:

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

run

> source ~/.bashrc

After setting GOPATH and PATH this did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For **Linux** you can also use this:

```
sudo apt install go-bindata
```

**Windows**(from comment by @kundan-roy):

```
choco install go-bindata
```

**MacOS**(from comment by @okan-cetin):

```
brew install go-bindata
```

Comment: Or if you are using Windows then run this command 
"choco install go-bindata"

Comment: And for macOS `brew install go-bindata`